# excel VBA query AD last log in user

Tags: vba, excel, active-directory, ldap

I have created an Excel 2010 ss that querys AD user LDAP and populates 3 columns pc name, description and online/offline.

I would now like to add the last user logged in.

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://FQDN;(objectCategory=computer);Name,Description;subtree"
```

Do I have to do this again?

```
objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://FQDN;(objectCategory=user);sAMAccount;subtree"
```

and how do I get it linked to the specific PC or is there a way to query the pc name last user logged in? I must say I'm pretty new to this and getting this far was to say the least educational.
Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: Have you tried executing the extra command to see if it works?  I'm not sure what your question is?  Are there two questions in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. AD does not store the PC the user last logged in to. You'd have to build something custom to track this. It's not really trivial to build either.
2. For your search for the current computer object, you'd want to filter that down a little to `(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=<PC NAME>$))`.
3. In the search for a user, you want the `sAMAccountName` attribute (you have sAMAccount).